# How to compile and build Java eclipse code through Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have local copy of Git java code.I want a pipeline job script in Jenkins that can compile and build the code locally and show success or failure .

I need a script which use only Java JDK not the maven (as the source code is developed using eclipse java project).

The os i am using is windows.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {  
        stage ("build") {
            tools {
               jdk "jdk-1.8.0_181"
            }
            steps {
                sh 'java -version'
            }
        }          
   }}
```

I am getting below error

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 7: Tool type "jdk" does not have an install of "jdk-1.8.0_181" configured - did you mean "Oracle JDK 8"? @ line 7, column 24.
                      jdk 'jdk-1.8.0_181'
                          ^

1 error

Comment: Is "jdk-1.8.0_181" version installed on that system? If installed, can you check did you configure jdk options in Jenkins global settings ?

Answer (score 2):

The `tools` section is expecting you to provide the **Name** to a specific item in your **Global Tool Configuration** (https://JENKINS_HOME/configureTools, or **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure Global Tools**).

On that page, when you click on the **JDK installations...** button, it will give you a list of all of the JDKs that are configured. Your pipeline step needs to specify one of the items by **Name** instead of by **Version**.

Based on the error hint, I suspect there is one called `Oracle JDK 8`; you just need to verify that it is pointing to the appropriate version and update your pipeline section to read:

```
tools {
    jdk "Oracle JDK 8"
}
```

---

Reference: The [Jenkins Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) page's [tools](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools) [example](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools-example) includes the following note (emphasis theirs):

> The tool name must be pre-configured in Jenkins under **Manage Jenkins → Global Tool Configuration**.

Comment: As you suggested i have changed the configuration but now its giving some other error

Comment: Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinsJavaJob
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinsJavaJob] Running shell script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)

Comment: Try using the `bat` step to execute instead of `sh`: [reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#windows)

Comment: Thanks its working now i have used the below       command sh 'java -version'